# How to design this in xml?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have absolutely no idea on how to implement this design as listview in android. Can anyonee help me or suggest me? I just need to know how to implement that blue arrow part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to implement this, I would create this blue arrows as PNG images, because it looks like you just have a certain amount of them. Then I would add the images to the right of the list element.

This link could help for my described solution:
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

More Detail: Like Bubu said, the picture need to be in a ImageView. Use GIMP for the creation of Icons or ImageButtons. That's how I do it, and GIMP helps me a lot for this purpose (Resizing, Pasting, Cutting etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Add an ImageView in your ListView item layout and set this ImageView in your ListView adapter in terms of the kind of item. You can set the ImageView background with the blue arrow in your xml file and the ImageView source with the correct drawable in your adapter.